# How to avoid empty 'thebibliography' environment (bibtex) if there are no references?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, conditionals, warnings

I have a general and central preamble for a lot of similar-style documents (several dozens) and most of the documents have a Bibliography at the beginning, so I call

```
\bibliographystyle{alphadin}
\bibliography{refs}
```

in the central preamble to avoid a lot of duplicate code and to be able to change the bibliography style centrally. But sadly, a minority of these documents has an empty bibliography. And these give me a warning about an empty thebibliography environment. But the bigger problem is: the bibliography headline still appears in the pdf output.

Is there a way to only get the bibliography headline and no warning when there is a non-empty bibliography? What would be the correct counters or booleans to address? Or is there an easy-to-use option?

Minmal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
  \bibliographystyle{alphadin}
  \bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

Run latex, bibtex, latex, latex.
Get for test.bbl

```
LaTeX Warning: Empty `thebibliography' environment on input line 10.
```

Entering the "patch" doesn't solve the problem. What I want ist: If there's no \cite{} within the document, don't display the bibliography.

Content of bbl:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{}

% this bibliography is generated by alphadin.bst [8.2] from 2005-12-21

\providecommand{\url}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\expandafter\ifx\csname urlstyle\endcsname\relax
  \providecommand{\doi}[1]{doi: #1}\else
  \providecommand{\doi}{doi: \begingroup \urlstyle{rm}\Url}\fi

\end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: I'm puzzled why you would have the instruction `\bibliography{refs}` in the *preamble* of any of your documents. This instruction belongs in the *body* of the document, in the place where the bibliography section should be created.

Comment: Sorry, I was to unclear about that. It is in the body, but my file "preamble.tex" ends with \begin{document} \bibliography{refs} because it's the same for almost all documents (but not all, hence the question/problem).

Comment: Thanks for this clarification. But, now, what strikes me as being rather unusual is that you would have `\bibliography{refs}` as the very first instruction following `\begin{document}`.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146348/conditional-bibliography-insertion and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/463498/printing-the-bibliography-conditionally-by-hooking-cite-to-toggle-a-boolean

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A test if the argument of `thebibliography` is empty

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\myBib\thebibliography
\let\endmyBib\endthebibliography 
\renewcommand\thebibliography[1]{\ifx\relax#1\relax\else\myBib{#1}\fi}
\begin{document}
foo
  \bibliographystyle{alphadin}
  \bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you need the `\myBibend` definition (and/or should it be `\let` to `\endthebibliography`)?

Comment: This of course will execute `\endtrivlist`

Comment: @Mico: yes, you're right. That should be the other way round, but makes no difference in this special case.

Answer (score 6):

### Method environment `thebibliography` that is really empty

This method catches the case (with or without empty line inbetween):

```
\begin{thebibliography}{...}

\end{thebibliography}
```

The patch for environment `thebibliography` looks for `\end` right after `\begin{thebibliography}`. Also an empty line before `\end` is supported. If `\end` is found, then the environment is ignored.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\@ifdefinable{org@thebibliography}{%
  \let\org@thebibliography\thebibliography
  \def\thebibliography#1{%
    \@ifnextchar\par{%
      \par@thebibliography{#1}%
    }{%
      \check@thebibliography{#1}{}%
    }%
  }%
  \newcommand{\par@thebibliography}[2]{%
    \check@thebibliography{#1}{\par}%
  }%
  \newcommand{\check@thebibliography}[2]{%
    \@ifnextchar\end{%
      \let\endthebibliography\relax
    }{%
      \org@thebibliography{#1}#2%
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \bibliographystyle{alpha}
  \bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

No warnings, no pages.

(Edit: matching the example in the question).

### Method that checks the protocol file `.blg` of `bibtex`

If there are not any citations, `bibtex` complains with an error:

```
I found no \citation commands---while reading file test.aux
```

This error message is also written in the `.blg` file.

The patch looks for that error message and excludes the bibliography, if the error message can be found.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newif\ifblg@empty
\IfFileExists{\jobname.blg}\@firstofone\@gobble{%
  \RequirePackage{xstring}%
  \begingroup
    \fullexpandarg
    % Method for reading the file is taken from `graphics.sty'.
    \newif\ifblg@read
    \blg@readtrue
    \openin\@inputcheck=\jobname.blg\relax
    \let\do\@makeother
    \dospecials
    \loop
      \read\@inputcheck to\@tempa
      \ifeof\@inputcheck
        \blg@readfalse
      \else
        \IfBeginWith*{\@tempa}
                    {I found no \@backslashchar citation commands}{%
          \global\blg@emptytrue
          \blg@readfalse
        }{}%
      \fi
      \ifblg@read
    \repeat
    \immediate\closein\@inputcheck
  \endgroup
}
\ifblg@empty
  \RequirePackage{version}%
  \excludeversion{thebibliography}%
\fi
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \bibliographystyle{alphadin}
  \bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

### Method based on empty argument of `thebibliography`

@egreg suggested to check the argument of `thebibliography`. If it is empty, then
it is assumed that the bibliography is empty (updated):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{version}
\makeatletter
\@ifdefinable{org@thebibliography}{%
  \let\org@thebibliography\thebibliography
  \def\thebibliography#1{%
    \def\@tempa{#1}%
    \ifx\@tempa\@empty
      \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
    {%
      \let\endthebibliography\relax
      \end{thebibliography}%
      \excludeversion{thebibliography}%
      \begin{thebibliography}{}%
    }{%
      \org@thebibliography{#1}%
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \bibliographystyle{alphadin}
  \bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this still gives me the warning... I don't use natbib, could this be the reason?

Comment: There are tons of bibliography packages. I had to use one for an example. If you are using `biblatex`, then it does not use the environment `thebibliography`, but it suppresses the section title if there aren't references. It gives a warning. Do you mean that warning?

Comment: I added a minimal exampel and the exact warning. You code does not solve the problem.

Comment: Your example works for me with the patch and without warning. What's the contents of your empty `.bbl` file?

Comment: added the content of bbl

Comment: Ah, I found the problem. I actually use the style alphadin, not amsalpha. I was not aware that the created bbl could be so much different. Your code works with amsalpha, but not with alphdin.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Another idea might be to check whether the argument to `\begin{thebibliography}` is empty.

Comment: I changed the question to alphadin.

Comment: I have the same issue and your answer look interesting to me...but it doesn't work...wich is very strange

Answer (score 4):

No citation in the document will make BibTeX write

```
\begin{thebibliography}{}
```

in the `.bbl` file. So we can check whether the argument is empty, because a citation will put the widest entry in the argument.

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\origthebibliography\thebibliography
\let\origendthebibliography\endthebibliography
\newif\ifemptybibliography
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
 {\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\emptybibliographytrue\else\origthebibliography{#1}\fi}
 {\ifemptybibliography\else\origendthebibliography\fi}


\begin{document}
x%\cite{HH}


  \bibliographystyle{alphadin}
  \bibliography{/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/doc/plain/texbytopic/tex}
\end{document}
```

Check uncommenting the citation.