# Conditional Bibliography insertion

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I am autogenerating several LaTeX documents from the same base. Some of them have a `\cite` inside, so I want to include a Bibliography. I am using bibtex and it is perfectly working.

However sometimes, I can have a document without any `\cite` inside, thus my final document appears with an Empty bibliography. Is it possible to include a bibliography only it there are references in it?
Of course, because documents are autogenerated, I need to have the same management for all documents, so not calling bibtex is not an acceptable solution for me.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: With biblatex/biber this would work automatically: `\printbibliography` prints only something if there is an entry.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do you want to make that into an answer?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74476/how-to-avoid-empty-thebibliography-environment-bibtex-if-there-are-no-refere?rq=1 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/463498/printing-the-bibliography-conditionally-by-hooking-cite-to-toggle-a-boolean

Comment: (I'm disappointed that the only answer suggests biblatex.  I'll try it, but I recall that I had previously decided that I needed to avoid biblatex.  Can't find the remarks on TeX.SE that lead me to that conclusion, though.)

Answer (score 3):

With `biblatex/biber` this would work automatically: `\printbibliography` prints only something if there is an entry.

Comment: Another question off the list. Thanks :-)