# Printing the bibliography conditionally by hooking \cite to toggle a boolean

Tags: bibliographies, conditionals

I want to print the Bibliography slide only if there were any citations in the presentation.
To that end I have redefined the `\cite` command to include the toggling of a boolean.
I tried multiple versions to redefine the command as well as different ways to define booleans.
The redefined version of the command contains a `\typeout` for debugging purposes and that's triggered as shown by pdflatex' log.
Nevertheless the MWE below does print `showbib false` and I am probably missing something obvious but can't figure it out. :(
If I toggle the boolean manually in the text with `\showbibtrue` it actually works.

**Why doesn't `\showbibtrue` work within `\cite`?**

FWIW, I have tested it to be not related to beamer (feel free to test/provide a solution with `article` instead).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{bib.bib}
@misc{foo,
  author="foo bar",
  title="getting things done",
}
\end{filecontents*}

\let\oldcite\cite
\newif\ifshowbib
\showbibfalse
\renewcommand{\cite}{\showbibtrue\typeout{within cite}\oldcite}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{sigh}
  \cite{foo}
\end{frame}

\ifshowbib
  \begin{frame}[c,allowframebreaks]{Bibliography}
    \typeout{showbib true}
    showbib true
    \bibliography{bib}
  \end{frame}
\else
  \typeout{showbib false}
  showbib false
\fi

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146348/conditional-bibliography-insertion and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74476/how-to-avoid-empty-thebibliography-environment-bibtex-if-there-are-no-refere?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trouble here is the grouping implicit in at least the `frame` environment of the example

```
\renewcommand{\cite}{\global\showbibtrue\typeout{within cite}\oldcite}
```

works.

A very simple example based on the `article` class can avoid grouping and can get away without the `\global`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\let\oldcite\cite
\newif\ifshowbib
\showbibfalse
\renewcommand{\cite}{\showbibtrue\typeout{within cite}\oldcite}

\begin{document}
\cite{doody}

\ifshowbib
  showbib true
  \bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\else  
  showbib false
\fi
\end{document}
```

---

Here is an alternative that avoids patching `\cite` (it might require one more LaTeX run to show the bibliography than the version that patches `\cite`). The `\global` is still required since the command `\citation` is read from the `.aux` and executed in a group.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\bibliographystyle{plain}

\newif\ifshowbib
\showbibfalse
\def\citation#1{\global\showbibtrue}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{sigh}
  \cite{doody}
\end{frame}

\ifshowbib
  \begin{frame}[c,allowframebreaks]{Bibliography}
    \typeout{showbib true}
    showbib true
    \bibliography{biblatex-examples}
  \end{frame}
\else
  \typeout{showbib false}
  showbib false
\fi

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, scoping! ;) Why can we just `\def` `\citation`, isn't it used for something (else)?

Comment: @stefanct The LaTeX kernel has `\let\citation\@gobble`, so it is not used for something else there. It seems to be a sort of universal hook that other packages can use (though `source2e` does not say that) and some do (e.g. `bibtopic`, `revtex4`).

Comment: Not an issue for me, but just to be clear: this would break when these packages are used?

Comment: @stefanct Depends on the package code: Either my answer breaks, the package breaks or the package uses a clever way to avoid that.