# Import .bib file into .tex file

Tags: bibtex

How can I import a .bib (Latex Bibliography) file into a .tex (Latex)? There must be separate files but there must be a bibliography into the .tex file.

Answer (score 8):

Your question is pretty unclear to me, feel free to add any further detail to it.

You may create one text file `mybib.bib` with contents formatted as follows:

```
@Book{JS2015,
  Title                    = {Once Upon a Time on Stack Overflow},
  Author                   = {{Smith, J.}},
  Year                     = {2015},
  Edition                  = {1th},
  Address                  = {Houston, TX},
  Publisher                = {United Publishers}
}
```

and, in the same folder, one file `main.tex`, [with at least one citation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74476/how-to-avoid-empty-thebibliography-environment-bibtex-if-there-are-no-refere/74490#74490):

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Text ... citation: \cite{JS2015}.

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{mybib}

\end{document}
```

You save and compile this latter, then compile the bibliography, then compile again one last time.

This is, very briefly, *How can I import a .bib (Latex Bibliography) file into a .tex (Latex)*, standard way. Please post a comment if something is not yet clear to you.

Comment: The double braces in `author = {{Smith, J.}},` stop BibTeX from parsing the name properly and from splitting it into family and given name. For people's names there should be no second pair of braces, it should be `author = {Smith, J.},` the extra set of braces is only necessary for corporate authors (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10808/35864).