# Compile with Bibtex but I don't want any citation

Tags: bibtex, citing, compiling, texmaker

I think this question is pretty vague, and I can delete it if needed.

I have a huge report template, which include every chapter. I've done it so I can compile each part in Texmaker via pdflatex > bibtex > pdflatex. It works well but for some files (like my frontpage or my result), I don't need to \cite anything. I also use natbib whith custom `.bst`

So when I compile these files, I get the error `no citations founds` from bibtex, which is understable. My actual solution is to cite a "blank" citation for these parts, but it's not satisfying, as it takes place a the end of my file pdf for nothing.

**Is there a way to compile these files with bibtex and without any citation or bibliography?** Like changing the behaviour of `\bibliography` in these files ?

*Yes I'm lazy and don't want to change my texmaker settings when I edit on file with citation or another with no citation.
I can add some code if you need it, but with multiple file it's long...*

Comment: I just found that I can add `\renewcommand{\refname}{}` to suppress the "Reference" section title, but there is still one reference minimum to have...

Comment: Add `\nocite{*]` to your preamble.

Comment: Well no, this command ad everycitation in the bibliography. I don't want any bibliography, because I cite no thing...

Comment: Well, if you don't want any bibliography, don't use bibtex… B.t.w. this command has to be used just once.

Comment: I thought of this option, but I precise in my question why I'm curious of finding even a tricky way of getting around it. I work with multiple chapter, and I don't really want to change the compilation way every time I change of chapter edition. Another way of thinking this is a modification of `\bibliography` so it don't use Bibtex when there are no citation in the document... like this : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74476/how-to-avoid-empty-thebibliography-environment-bibtex-if-there-are-no-refere

Comment: `latexmk` is a nice tool that detects how often LaTeX needs to be run and runs auxiliary programs like BibTeX, Biber as well. That could help here since `latexmk` would know not to run BibTeX if there is no bibliography setup at all.

Comment: I will give it a try, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

A way to work around this is to chnage Texmaker compilation way in order to check for the existance of citation in the file.aux before using bibtex.

When I was compiling, I used this command for pdflatex>bibtex>pdflatex(x2)>viewpdf

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --enable-write18 %.tex | bibtex %.aux |pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --enable-write18 %.tex |pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --enable-write18 %.tex |evince %.pdf
```

I have set a small shell script that check for \citation in the file before executing bibtex.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$1" ];
  then FILE="$1"
  if [[ ! -z $(grep "\citation" "$FILE") ]];
    then bibtex $FILE;
  fi
fi
```

and so my compilation command work like this

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --enable-write18 %.tex | ./diffBibtex.sh %.aux |pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --enable-write18 %.tex |pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --enable-write18 %.tex |evince %.pdf
```

It works now, but I see multiple drawback to this right now. I depend on a custom script that may just work in linux environment. Secondly, I need to make sur every .aux is removed before new compilation if I add a citation or remove all of them. 
Finally this is working because it's used in a local workflow but I don't know yet if the cost in term of sharing my template will be huge.

Any answer is still welcome

Comment: Maybe you should check if the `.tex` file contains any `\cite{...}` instead of mucking with `.aux`. Or make sure the check is only done after running e.g. `pdflatex`.

Comment: Its what I do, I run `pdflatex` and after I run my script `diffBibtex.sh` that run `bibtex` only if there is at least one `\citation`. Checking for `\cite` could delete the drawback of removing every `file.aux` before compilation, but then all the compilation process rely on 1 script, and I'm not confident enought at this moment to code such a reliable script. In fact, I didn't achieved to understand how texmaker share the filename with `&`, and how to use this information in a custom script.